# Why every data change in aggregates should be in transaction?

Tags: transactions, domain-driven-design

Given an Order aggregate it consists of Order and OrderItems.  Order is the aggregate root.  Placing an order is the only scenario that requires a transaction for data consistency.  Or at least there are a lot of scenarios involves changing data both in order and orderItems that do NOT require transaction.

Before DDD, transaction is a decision made during creating methods.  You typically think whether this method or behavior need to be in transaction in order to maintain consistency.

DDD suggests to make a transaction for every possible behavior exposed by aggregate root.  This actually can lead to more deadlocks.

I think I don't have to implement every data changing behavior in the aggregate root to be in transaction.

For example if you change only shipping details, why would you need a transaction.  If you only deleting an order item, why would you need a transaction.  So for methods Order.UpdateOrder, and Order.DeleteOrderItem, we should not consider transactions.

Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you miss something. If you design your aggregates correctly, more especially if you make them sufficiently small, then you won't have pointless transactions, at least not a lot of them. Your aggregates should be highly cohesive so properties/state that are modified concurrently should stay in the same aggregate; that is the point of an aggregate, to protect concurrent access to state.

If your aggregates are bigger than they should be then there is a great change that the aggregates `force-field` is too wide and commands that are not cohesive will be serialized for nothing.

About the `orders`, there would not be a lot of failed transactions because the probability to add an `order item` and to change the `order shipping details` at the same time is very low.

Anyway, deadlocks won't occur because of transactions in any case, but failed transactions could occur.

Comment: For deadlocks possibility check this post.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34662578/in-domain-driven-design-why-would-you-use-an-aggregate-object-and-what-key-pr

Comment: I say that not all behaviors in root aggregate need to be in transaction.
I think we should consider transaction when consistency issue is possible, and that should be based on analyzing the behavior.

For example if you change only shipping details, why you would need a transaction.  If you only deleting an order item, why would need a transaction.  So in methods Order.UpdateOrder, and Order.DeleteOrderItem, we should not consider transactions.

Comment: @Costa But you need transactions in those cases, otherwise it could get messy depending on your repository implementation. Keep in mind that the aggregate is loaded entirely when/before it processes a command, there should be no lazy-loading.

Comment: @Costa it´s all about business transactions what DDD stands for, maybe you are mapping your mind to technical transactions such as SQL. The fact of adding a Product to an Order is a business transaction. If you use Mongo you won´t have transactions at all, if you use MySql you will have to make the scope of the ACID transaction to match the aggregate boundary, that´s it. Everything is a business transaction and the theory says that a use case should affect only 1 aggregate state (that's a business transaction)

Answer (score 0):

In the purest form your repository would have very few methods:

```
public interface IAggregateRepository
{
    AggregateRoot Get(Guid id);
    void Save(AggregateRoot instance);
}
```

There is no distinction between use cases/commands in this scenario.  You wouldn't necessarily know whether or not a transaction is required.

Another consideration is that transactions should be handled in the integration/application *layer*.  This moves the transaction handling even further from the domain interactions.

You *could* have the application be aware of specific use-cases and decide to forego transactions for certain commands.  However, this may be more effort that it is worth.

A last point is that a transaction is not always only about what *you* are doing but also about what *others* are doing.

I would err on the side of caution and rather use a transaction.  If there is a specific reason to not use a transaction then that is certainly an option but that seems more appropriate for reads.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a need somewhere in the system to update just a shipping details, than following core DDD approach you may have a different bounded context with different aggregate, let's call it `ShippingRequest`, which has just two fields, `OrderId` and `ShippingDetails`, and which eventually may or may not map to the same underlying table. Then this aggregate is implicitly covered by transaction as it maps to just one table.

Or maybe you don't want to care about all these bounded contexts, ubiquitous languages and aggregates, because DDD is not worth to implement and some traditional CRUD/transaction script approach is enough.

Problem also is that DDD is often time explained on wrong examples like this one. Aggregate defines some consistency boundary, some invariant that represents your business rule. So in case of Order as an Aggregate, let's say order is assigned a maximum allowable total, which must not be exceeded. Than this become a natural aggregate, because whenever you want to add or delete an item, whole aggregate must be retrieved and updated as a single atomic unit.

Comment: Even without max total, OrderItem cannot live in the model without Order, so it cannot be aggregate root, it must be a part of Order aggregate.

Comment: Sure it can be, if it has property OrderId, which you must assign from constructor...

Comment: OrderID attribute cannot be added to OrderItem because it is against OO Encapsulation.

Comment: Well with this logic even your Order can't be an aggregate, because you might say that it can't live in the model without Customer. But you probably have an CustomerId attribute on Order. Does this break encapsulation?

Comment: Good argument
However pure OOD prevents you to access an attribute belongs to another object.
Regarding DDD, I think both Customer and Order should be aggregate roots.  Still I don't have answer for your question so far !!

Comment: Yes, and that's where the term "bounded context" comes into play. As there can be some context where exists Order aggregate, that doesn't care about any Customer aggregate existing in a different context, than there can exist OrderItem aggregate, that doesn't care about Order aggregate existing in a different context.

Comment: Let us assume the two aggregates are in the same context, a way to verify an aggregate is to check whether it is possible to apply aggregate rules.  Aggregate Root controls the life cycle of children, children will die once root is died.  In case of OrderItem it does not make a sense to live in the system without Order.  However deleting an Order does not mean to kill the customer.  So Customer and Order are roots however orderItem cannot be root.

Comment: In case of Order it does not make a sense to live in the system without Customer as well and deleting OrderItem doesn't kill Order as well. So modeling aggregates in the end depends on your point of view.

Comment: I would say it depends on common sense (point of view).  but also depends on the definition of Aggregate: 
It is a cluster of objects treated as a unit for the purpose of data change.  Also you can verify whether you chose the aggregate root by applying aggregate rules.  and if all rules satisfied then go ahead.